# groovy + Spring add list in different order will throw NotWritablePropertyException

Tags: spring, groovy

I am trying to integrate Groovy with Spring.
In one bean I would need to put in a list as property
However that only work if I define the item in list before the bean definition.

To avoid future errors...I would like to ask what is the mechanism behind compiling the context and causing the error?

The Item.groovy is a simple bean with field String itemName

My config is like

**Not-working**

```
<lang:groovy id="handler" script-source="ItemHandlerImpl.groovy">
  <lang:property name="itemList">
    <list>
      <lang:groovy id="item1" script-source="Item.groovy">
        <lang:property name="itemName" value="name1" />
      </lang:groovy>
    </list>
  </lang:property>
</lang:groovy>
```

This throws

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'itemName' of bean class [org.springframework.scripting.groovy.GroovyScriptFactory]: Bean property 'itemName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1024)
                at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:900)
                at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
                at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
                ... 70 more
```

After many attempts, this is my **working config**

```
<lang:groovy id="item1" script-source="Item.groovy">
  <lang:property name="itemName" value="name1" />
</lang:groovy>

<lang:groovy id="handler" script-source="ItemHandlerImpl.groovy">
  <lang:property name="itemList">
    <list>
      <ref bean ="item1">
    </list>
  </lang:property>
</lang:groovy>
```

Comment: you should provide groovy code for Item.groovy. From stacktrace, Spring states that your bean property "itemName" is not writable, so i doubt you only change configuration like in question, more like you added property itemName in your Item.groovy code.

Comment: the Item.groovy is really a simple bean with field itemName
With that error message I had same doubt, but I reproduce the "working" result and "not work result" by just changing the spring config